# How to count and sum a field between 2 dates?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is my model file:

income.js

```
var incomeSchema = new schema({
  issuedBy: { type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
  amount: {type: Number, default: 0},
  content: { type: String, default :''},
  note: { type: String, default: ''}
}, {timestamps: true});
```

Now I want to sum the all values of amount between 2 dates and count and export all the data between these dates into a table.

For example: I want to sum all the amount between Feb 12 2017 and Feb 23 2017 and shows it like this:

1.Number of transactions: 20

2.Total: $2500

3.The table that display all the data between 2 dates.

I have tried some answer using

```
collection.find( {'createdAt': {$gte: Date, $lte: Date}}
```

but I still can't do it.

Any solution will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below aggregation.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [{
        $match: {
            createdAt: {
                $gte: new Date('2017-02-12'),
                $lte: new Date('2017-02-23')
            }
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            Total: {
                $sum: "$amount"
            },
            NoOfTransactions: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }]
)
```

You can use $out stage to write to a new collection.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with simple do like this.

```
db.collection.find({ "field" : { $gt: value1, $lt: value2 } } );    // value1 < field < value
```

or 
First, in the Schema, you need to define the type of the date field to be:

```
{date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }}
```

then when u query for the date range:

```
db.collection.find({"field": {'$gte': new Date('3/1/2014'), '$lt': new Date('3/16/2014')}});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion but I only retrieve 1 record. I mentioned in my question your suggestion.

Comment: may be you have only one record in your collection that matches with our requirement

Comment: I found the problem... I thought $lte is less than or equal, but it seems only retrieve smaller record. I tried to change the date to the previous day and it worked well.